# insert a column to the left of cell vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through a header row and insert an entire column to the left based on certain conditions.

```
Sub InsertCol()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 20
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Cells(1, i).Columns.Insert  ' this only inserts a cell..need an entire column
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Columns(i).Insert`

```
Sub InsertCol()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 20
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Columns(i).Insert
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Note that you may want to step backwards through this loop since you're inserting columns:

```
Sub InsertCol()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 20 To 1 Step -1
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Columns(i).Insert
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something more like

```
Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
```

This will insert a column to the left of the specified range ("B:B") in my example.

You also don't need to refer to the full range, you can just refer to i so.

```
Columns(i).Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
```